# How can I create "new" fields from an existing string with $Project?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents in this format:

{ _id = ..., description = "Foo Bar Baz | SX=123 | SY=456" },
.
.
.

I have to use the values mentioned in the text field as SX and SY to provide some statistics.

Is there any way to "Project" new fields SX and SY within the aggregation framework so I can work with those fields in the aggregation pipeline?

Thanks
   Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As at MongoDB 2.4, there is no [Aggregation Framework operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) that will split/parse a string (as per your example of a `description` field).

There are a few relevant feature requests that you can watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker:

- [SERVER-6773: Operator for splitting string based on a separator](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6773)
- [SERVER-8951: Add $find operator for strings](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8951)
- [SERVER-11947: $project filter using $regex](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947)

Until one or more of the above options are implemented in the Aggregation Framework, you will either have to:

- 1) use [Map/Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) for your aggregation query

OR

- 2) iterate your documents from application code in order to extract and add the additional fields needed before running your Aggregation Framework query