# Mongo Aggregation / Grouping Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have records of this form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57993e64498e9bebb535154f"),
    "fooKey" : "123|a|b|c|||d",
    "locationId" : 1,
    "type" : "FOO"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579e0a3d498e9bebb545ff96"),
    "fooKey" : "123|x|y|z|||v",
    "locationId" : 1,
    "type" : "FOO"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a5443b498e381a40a26afb"),
    "fooKey" : "123|a|b|c|||d",
    "locationId" : 2,
    "type" : "FOO"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a63fef498e381a40a60347"),
    "fooKey" : "123|x|y|z|||v",
    "locationId" : 2,
    "type" : "FOO"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579ab3ce498e9538125052ca"),
    "fooKey" : "456|h|j|j|||k",
    "locationId" : 2,
    "type" : "BAR"
}
```

I went through the documentation and this seems like it could be complex given that I need this today (and I am not an expert in Mongo).  What I need an aggregation query (for only records with "type" : "FOO") to return groups grouped by:

- The first field in the pipe-delimited string in the "fooKey" field (for example "123"
- The locationId

and then where the resulting count of the type field (where it is specifically equal to "FOO" is greater than 1.

That is given the records above I need something along the lines of records 1 and 2 returned in a group along with records 3 and 4 aggregated in a group... along with a count of the group size.

**Expected Output**

Something like this:

```
{ 
    "foo": "123", 
    "locationId": 1, 
    "type": "FOO", 
    "total": 2 
}, 
{ 
    "foo": "123", 
    "locationId": 2,
    "type": "FOO", 
    "total": 2 
}
```

Comment: Something like this:{
   foo: “123",
   "locationId" : 1,
   type: "FOO",
   total: 2
},
{
   foo: “123",
   "locationId" : 2,
   type: "FOO",
   total: 2
}

Comment: Also there could be many distinct types of foo's for fooKeys.... foo is like a person Id.

Comment: [Most efficient way to change a string field value to its substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832525/most-efficient-way-to-change-a-string-field-value-to-its-substring)

Comment: Unless your first token in the pipe delimited fooKey will always be the same length, I don't think you can do this in the current version of MongoDB using aggregate.

Comment: Is there a regex way to do it?

Comment: It looks like the split operation can split the tokens of the pipe-delimited string into an array to take the first element.

Comment: This returns me back what I want -- IF I had the "foo" field in the original records:db.somecollection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "foo": "$foo",
            "locationId": "$locationId"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}
])    but I really don't want to be adding extra fields on a production document database.

Comment: I am on Mongo 2.4.  According to this link (where someone is asking an almost identical question), there is no way to accomplish the above (without using MR)?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118774/how-can-i-create-new-fields-from-an-existing-string-with-project